# Reuse 'azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin' for brand new "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route" in existed azure front door configuration

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

**In short,I would like to:**

- add `"azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route"` to an ***existed** azure front door configuration*

Due to [terraform specification](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cdn_frontdoor_route), **one of the required parameters is**
`cdn_frontdoor_origin_ids`

[*(Required) One or more Front Door Origin resource IDs that this Front Door Route will link to*]

**What has been done:**

So, my first intention was to inquired necessary information **from existed origin** by the dedicated tf data source, but unfortunately it looks like, azurerm tf provider, doesn't support a data source for `azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin` resource

[image]

**P.s**
So, again, the question, that bothering me, how such kind of the setup can be managed

Will be appreciated with any suggestion

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have initially created the origin and other using following code:

```
resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "examplekavv.com"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile" "example" {
  name                = "exampleprofile"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
   sku_name            = "Standard_AzureFrontDoor"
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group" "example" {
  name                     = "example-origin-group"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.id
  session_affinity_enabled = true

  restore_traffic_time_to_healed_or_new_endpoint_in_minutes = 10

  health_probe {
    interval_in_seconds = 240
    path                = "/healthProbe"
    protocol            = "Https"
    request_type        = "HEAD"
  }

  load_balancing {
    additional_latency_in_milliseconds = 0
    sample_size                        = 16
    successful_samples_required        = 3
  }
}

output "cdngroup" {
  value = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.example
  
}


data "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group" "all_groups" {
  name                     = "example-origin-group"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  profile_name = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.name
  //cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.id
}

output "cdn_origin_groupname" {
  value = data.azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.all_groups.health_probe
}


resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin" "example" {
  name                          = "example-origin"
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_group_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.example.id
  enabled                       = true

  certificate_name_check_enabled = false

  host_name          = "contoso.com"
  http_port          = 80
  https_port         = 443
  origin_host_header = "www.contoso.com"
  priority           = 1
  weight             = 1
}
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint" "example" {
  name                     = "example-endpoint"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.id
  
}


data "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint" "all_endpoints" {
  name                = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint.example.name
  profile_name = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.name
  resource_group_name =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

output "frontDoorEndpointHostName" {
  value = data.azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint.all_endpoints.host_name
}



resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain" "contoso" {
  name                     = "contoso-custom-domain"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.id
  dns_zone_id              = azurerm_dns_zone.example.id
  host_name                = join(".", ["contoso", azurerm_dns_zone.example.name])

  tls {
    certificate_type    = "ManagedCertificate"
    minimum_tls_version = "TLS12"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain" "fabrikam" {
  name                     = "fabrikam-custom-domain"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.id
  dns_zone_id              = azurerm_dns_zone.example.id
  host_name                = join(".", ["fabrikam", azurerm_dns_zone.example.name])

  tls {
    certificate_type    = "ManagedCertificate"
    minimum_tls_version = "TLS12"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule_set" "example" {
  name                     = "kaexampleruleset"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule" "example" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.example, azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin.example]

  name                      = "examplerule"
  cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule_set.example.id
  order                     = 1
  behavior_on_match         = "Continue"

  actions {
    route_configuration_override_action {
      cdn_frontdoor_origin_group_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.example.id
      forwarding_protocol           = "HttpsOnly"
      query_string_caching_behavior = "IncludeSpecifiedQueryStrings"
      query_string_parameters       = ["foo", "clientIp={client_ip}"]
      compression_enabled           = true
      cache_behavior                = "OverrideIfOriginMissing"
      cache_duration                = "365.23:59:59"
    }

    url_redirect_action {
      redirect_type        = "PermanentRedirect"
      redirect_protocol    = "MatchRequest"
      query_string         = "clientIp={client_ip}"
      destination_path     = "/exampleredirection"
      destination_hostname = "contoso.com"
      destination_fragment = "UrlRedirect"
    }
  }

  conditions {
    host_name_condition {
      operator         = "Equal"
      negate_condition = false
      match_values     = ["www.contoso.com", "images.contoso.com", "video.contoso.com"]
      transforms       = ["Lowercase", "Trim"]
    }

    is_device_condition {
      operator         = "Equal"
      negate_condition = false
      match_values     = ["Mobile"]
    }

    post_args_condition {
      post_args_name = "customerName"
      operator       = "BeginsWith"
      match_values   = ["J", "K"]
      transforms     = ["Uppercase"]
    }

    request_method_condition {
      operator         = "Equal"
      negate_condition = false
      match_values     = ["DELETE"]
    }

    url_filename_condition {
      operator         = "Equal"
      negate_condition = false
      match_values     = ["media.mp4"]
      transforms       = ["Lowercase", "RemoveNulls", "Trim"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route" "example" {
  name                          = "example-route"
  cdn_frontdoor_endpoint_id     = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint.example.id
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_group_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.example.id
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_ids      = [azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin.example.id]
  cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_ids    = [azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule_set.example.id]
  enabled                       = true

  forwarding_protocol    = "HttpsOnly"
  https_redirect_enabled = true
  patterns_to_match      = ["/*"]
  supported_protocols    = ["Http", "Https"]

  cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain_ids = [azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain.contoso.id, azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain.fabrikam.id]
  link_to_default_domain          = false

  cache {
    query_string_caching_behavior = "IgnoreSpecifiedQueryStrings"
    query_strings                 = ["account", "settings"]
    compression_enabled           = true
    content_types_to_compress     = ["text/html", "text/javascript", "text/xml"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain_association" "contoso" {
  cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain.contoso.id
  cdn_frontdoor_route_ids        = [azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route.example.id]
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain_association" "fabrikam" {
  cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain.fabrikam.id
  cdn_frontdoor_route_ids        = [azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route.example.id]
}
```

[image]

I have tried to create data source for cdn frontdoor origin few ways i.e;

```
 data "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin" "example" {
      name = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin.example.name
    }
```

But as the document suggests and as you said there is no data source for that block.

[image]

- So , the only way I found is to use the resource Id of the existing origin of the origin group:
- Note the name of the origin from origins page of the origin group .

[image]

[image]

**Create a resource Id with following format:**

**ResourceId of origin:**
`/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup name>/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/<yourCDNprofilename>/originGroups/<origin-group-name>/origins/<desired-origin name>`

*In my case example:*

**`/subscriptions/b83c1ed3xxxx/resourceGroups/vx-xxx/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/exampleprofile/originGroups/example-origin-group/origins/example-origin`**

Change the `protocols` and cdn `custom domains` according to the requirement ,otherwise you may face following kind of errors due to conflicts as they can  have same configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain" "contoso" {
  name                     = "contoso-custom-domain"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.id
  dns_zone_id              = azurerm_dns_zone.example.id
  host_name                = join(".", ["contoso", azurerm_dns_zone.example.name])

  tls {
    certificate_type    = "ManagedCertificate"
    minimum_tls_version = "TLS12"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain" "kavya" {
  name                     = "kavya-custom-domain"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.id
  dns_zone_id              = azurerm_dns_zone.example.id
  host_name                = join(".", ["kavya", azurerm_dns_zone.example.name])

  tls {
    certificate_type    = "ManagedCertificate"
    minimum_tls_version = "TLS12"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain" "fabrikam" {
  name                     = "fabrikam-custom-domain"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.id
  dns_zone_id              = azurerm_dns_zone.example.id
  host_name                = join(".", ["fabrikam", azurerm_dns_zone.example.name])

  tls {
    certificate_type    = "ManagedCertificate"
    minimum_tls_version = "TLS12"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule_set" "example" {
  name                     = "kaexampleruleset"
  cdn_frontdoor_profile_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.id
}

Error: creating Front Door Route: (Route Name "example-route3" / Afd Endpoint Name "example-endpoint" / Profile Name "exampleprofile" / Resource Group "xx"): cdn.RoutesClient#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="The route domains, paths and protocols configuration has a conflict. More information: Domain: /subscriptions/xxx-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/xxxxxxe/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/exampleprofile/customDomains/fabrikam-custom-domain, Path pattern: /*, Protocol: Https cannot be added to Route example-route3 as this combination already exists in Endpoint example-endpoint, Route example-route.."
│   on main.tf line 321, in resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route" "example3":
│  321: resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route" "example3" {
```

[image]

***I have created azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route with existing origin as follows:***

*Example:*

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route" "example3" {
  name                          = "example-route3"
  cdn_frontdoor_endpoint_id     = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint.example.id
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_group_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.example.id
  cdn_frontdoor_origin_ids      = ["/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/exampleprofile/originGroups/example-origin-group/origins/example-origin"]
  cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_ids    = [azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_rule_set.example.id]
  enabled                       = true

  forwarding_protocol    = "HttpsOnly"
  https_redirect_enabled = true
  patterns_to_match      = ["/*"]
  supported_protocols    = ["Http","Https"]

  cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain_ids = [azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain.<anyname>.id]
  link_to_default_domain          = false

  cache {
    query_string_caching_behavior = "IgnoreSpecifiedQueryStrings"
    query_strings                 = ["account", "settings"]
    compression_enabled           = true
    content_types_to_compress     = [ "text/xml"]
  }
}
```

[image]

Two routes with same origin created.

[image]

**Reference :** [cdn_frontdoor_origin_group | | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cdn_frontdoor_origin_group)